# Feature service is not added to map using ArcGIS API for JS?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to search features using the "esri/search" module. I'm passing the parameters to callback function (Search) to add a feature layer and search features, but i don't see any features added on map in first place. Please check below the function call:

```js
var mysources = mySearch.get("mysources");
mySearch.on("load", function(){
  mySearch.Set("mysources",mysources);
  mysources.push({
    myfeatureLayer: new FeatureLayer("http://arcgis-serveruf-1981283418.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/MyFiles/LandParcels/FeatureServer/0"),
      mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
      searchFields: ["ADDRESS"],
      suggestionTemplate: "Address : ${ADDRESS}",
      exactMatch: false,
      outFields: ["*"],
      name: "land parcels",
      labelSymbol: textSymbol,
      placeholder: "address of parcels",
      maxResults: 6,
      maxSuggestions: 6,
      enableSuggestions: true,
      minCharacters: 1
  });
  map.addLayer(myfeatureLayer);
});
```

Comment: "When using a Map with a SpatialReference other than Web Mercator or Geographic, be sure to set a default GeometryService".

Comment: I published a new feature service by changing the projection from NAD to Web Mercator. But i couldn't add the layer to map. I even declared the myfeatureLayer as separate variable as suggested by below, but still it remains un-added. Would you suggest were i had gone wrong ?. Thanks-Kirk

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explicitly defined `myfeatureLayer` as a variable, so it's not available when you try to run `map.addLayer(myfeatureLayer)`.

You could first declare `myfeaturelayer` as a variable, then add the variable to `mysources`, or you could get the last index of `mysources` and add that to the map.

Comment: I defined the myfeatureLayer as a variable before mysources, but still the layer did not show up on the basemap. Any reasons were i had gone wrong?.

Comment: Why does myfeatureLayer need to depend on the search function at all? Can you just create a feature layer and add it normally, as in [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_feature.html)? You're over-complicating things in the above example

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I fixed the issue. The features are not highlighted when i click the search with a related value or suggested results.